# How to terminate iOS app on button tap in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, app-store, offline

I have a scenario to implement in Swift when there is no internet connection and user opens my app. Then, I have to show an alert on MainScreen to inform user with an alert button called "Deny". So, if user choose to deny to enable mobile data, the app should be terminated.

Do you know what's the proper way to implement this feature that Apple will accept my app on App Store after this implementation? I saw previous posts related to this topic where the recommendation is exit(0) but Apple seems to strongly discourage it.

Comment: If your app requires an internet connection to operate, you should implement an error state for the scenario when there is no internet connection. You shouldn't deliberately terminate your app.

Comment: It's completely sufficient and best user experience, when you _just try_ a request. If it fails for what ever reason, show an alert and possibly a recovery suggestion. The user should be able to dismiss this alert which then reveals the "blank" or "data unavailable" view. A "retry" button there (when appropriate), would be even perfect.

Comment: You must not do that : your app will be rejected during AppStore review process.

Comment: What about the option to suspend the app in background? Apple will reject it as well?

Comment: There is no proper way to terminate an app. It something you cannot do. Period. And what do you mean suspend the app in the background? How do you propose suspending it? You can't control the lifecycle of the app, only the OS and the user can do that. Also an app can't enable mobile data anyway, so having a dialog about enabling it or not is pointless. Sounds like your entire GUI design and interaction needs rethinking in order to take IOS limitations in consideration.

Comment: Thank you all for your responses! We are going to change our design according to iOS limitations.

Answer (score 1):

Check if the device is connected to the Internet using the Reachability library on the landing page. If it is not connected to the internet as a result of the control, it should not go to the other screen and give a warning. It would be bad to force close the app.

Comment: "Preflight" checks are of limited use. On a mobile device the network can go away at any instant. You need robust error handling and retry logic in your network stack.